# Как удалить один объект по конкретному id из Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase, firebase-android

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне необходимо удалить или перезаписать объект, но мой код не находит его по id

```
fun saveNewTaskToDatabase(id:Int?){
    val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder().name("realmDB.realm").build()
    val realm = Realm.getInstance(config)
    val database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Tasks")

    val taskRealm = realm.copyFromRealm(realm.where(TaskRealmObjClass::class.java).equalTo("id", id).findFirst())
    val task = TaskKotlinClass(taskRealm?.id, taskRealm?.date_start.toString(), taskRealm?.date_finish.toString(), taskRealm?.name, taskRealm?.description)

    val tasksQuery = database.equalTo(id?.toDouble()!!, "id")
    database.child(tasksQuery.path.toString()).removeValue()
```

Comment: а какой id вы пытаетесь удалить?

Answer (score 0):

Может, это поможет.

Сначала надо записать все таски в массив, а потом уже в нём искать отдельный таск.
Вот, как я решала похожую задачу (прошу прощения за свой джаваскриптовый):

```
const getCards = (userId) => {
  const getCardsResult = db
    .ref("requests/")
    .orderByChild("owner")
    .equalTo(userId)
    .once("value")
    .then((snapshot) => {
      let items = [];

      snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
        items.push(childSnapshot.val());
      });

      return items;
    });
  return getCardsResult;
};

const getUserById = (id) => {
  return getUsers().then((users) => {
    const user = users.find((user) => user.id === id);
    // Ну и тут что нужно сделать с отдельным юзером
  });
};
```